# How to set up a widget for external wed pages with Laravel 4.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, laravel, laravel-4

I wanted to ask if there were any good resources or tutorials that would show me how to build widgets for external web-pages with Laravel 4.1.  Are there any built in tools within Laravel that would allow me to do this?  Basically I would like to build a widget that other websites can implement easily, and that I could derive and send info to (like a voting counter, etc..).  I tried following this tutorial: http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/.  But I was hoping that there was something that implements well with Laravel.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel offers packages to create modular functionality, but I think what you mean by a widget is not Laravel or Framework specific, but more a web standard way of developing reusable code. Of course it is possible to do this with Laravel, but I just wanted to tell that it is not Framework specific, otherwise the idea of making a widget that should be usable elsewhere useless.

This is the current status of the W3C widget-api:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-widgets-apis-20131031/

But what you can do of course--when building a reusable component--is:

- Writing the CSS so your component is responsive.
- Namespace you CSS properly so you don't get style collisions.
- Create JavaScript/jQuery which doesn't polutes the global namespace.

With all of this you are 70% there. You might do all of this in a folder like so:

```
widget
  |
  +-- /css
  |
  +-- /js
  |
  +-- index.html
```

Develop it like so and you will have the basic concept of a widget.

Sorry for not answering your question in a positive way.

Comment: Where would I put this folder in my Laravel project (would it just be anywhere?  In the public folder somewhere?), and how do I connect it to my controllers/models.

Comment: This is not really a structure that is supported yet. But you can simulate this with blade templates and include them where you want. I'm building a CMS in Laravel it's almost ready for beta. This might be something to include.